# Receiving access denied on HttpClient Post request

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and web requests, so I wanted to start with a simple post and just print out the response to console.

I've double checked the requests in chrome and with fiddler, and I get the correct response there, but in this program it returns "access denied".

```
        static async Task<string> GetWeatherAsync()
        {
            var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("User-Agent", "WeatherAhead")
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseString;
        }
```

The URL is the test one they provide in weather.gov's documentation and returns the json I'm expecting when I access it through the browser.

Thanks for any help, or suggestions you can provide!

Comment: Are you logged in on the browser? There may be some kind of authentication happening.

Comment: If you make the same exact request via C# that you make via the browser or Postman, then you will get the same response. Their server can't tell the difference. Meaning, you've failed to make the requests the same. So figure out what it is you're doing different. Tools like Fiddler can help you out with that. Check the HTTP headers specifically.

Comment: Yes, I was using Fiddler to try to mimic the headers, but based on @Hien Nguyen's response I was going about it wrong. I wish I could say I knew why mine was wrong, but I looked up several methods to try and figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these setting for client

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.weather.gov");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "web api client");
```

Change your function to this and it worked

```
static async Task < string > GetWeatherAsync() {

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.weather.gov");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "web api client");

        //var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892");
        var response = await client.GetAsync("/points/39.7456,-97.0892");
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseString;

}
```

Comment: in production you don't want to instantiated a new client with each request. it should be a class level static readonly. see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Sean Even that isn't sufficient to use HttpClient safely. See [this article](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html). That's partly why I use [Flurl](https://flurl.io). They have taken these issues into consideration and wrapped it in a nice fluent syntax.

Comment: @Hien the code you've shown is the flat out wrong way to use HttpClient. Saying it's just example code doesn't excuse that. Why would you give wrong example code? The entire point is to show the correct way to do things, not the wrong way. Particularly when you're trying to provide an authoritative answer. It's okay to not know the right way, HttpClient is particularly tricky. But once you've been told you're doing it wrong, fix your answer!

Comment: Hien and @mason, thank you it is working now! I added the ConnectionLeaseTimeout as suggested by the article you linked. While it may not have any effect on such basic code as this, it seems like something that would be good to get into a habit of doing.

Comment: @Aszuul Try out [Flurl](https://flurl.io/): it's simpler than using HttpClient and takes care of the little things like the connection lease timeout. And it easily convert the response from JSON to an object for you.